# Repeat Javascript/jQuery until specific outcome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following code that looks at an unordered list and selects a random item. I want to make sure the same 'li' doesn't get selected twice in a row, or even better, don't select a repeat li until all of them have been selected.

```
var list = $('#headshots li:visible').toArray();

var elemlength = list.length;
var randomitem = list[Math.floor(Math.random() * elemlength)];
```

Full code:

```
function sawpHomepageAgencyHeadshots() {
    var fullList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    window.setInterval(function(){
        var random = fullList.slice(0).sort(function() {
            return .5 - Math.random();
        });

        $('#headshots li').each(function() {
            var i = parseInt($(this).css('background-image').replace(/\D+/, ''));

            random = $.grep(random, function(value) { return value != i; });
        });

        var list = $('#headshots li:visible').toArray();

        var elemlength = list.length;
        var randomitem = list[Math.floor(Math.random()*elemlength)];

        $(randomitem).css({'background-image': 'url("' + absoluteDomainPath + 'images/headshots/headshot-' + random[0] + '.jpg")'});
    }, 3000);
}
```

Added fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MBP2t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the random item from the list variable, then it can not be selected again.
Take a look at this fiddle where I use an interval to select each item randomly.

http://jsfiddle.net/ghcNM/

```
var list = $('#headshots li:visible');
var loop = setInterval(doit, 500);

function doit(){
    if(list.length){
        randomitem = list.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length), 1)
        $(randomitem).css('background', '#ff0000');
    }else{
        clearInterval(loop);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already inside a interval. I have updated my original message to reflect the full code. Would you mind updating your answer?

Comment: post a fiddle so it is easy for me.

Comment: Here is my code inside your interval function. I'm really not sure what else you want help with.  
http://jsfiddle.net/MBP2t/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain state somewhere in your application, so there are two basic options here:

Do it in memory:

Keep an array of visited items, then, when you pull an item, check if it's in the list you've already seen. If it's not, add it to the list. If it is, randomly pick again.

Do it in the DOM:

Do you search for a node like this: `$('#headshots li:visible').not('.seen')`
After you've found an item, do item.addClass('seen') to mark it as seen, then continue.
Once your jQuery selector returns no values, you can remove the seen class from all elements.

For what it's worth, the second option is pretty gross.